# Paypal wallet creation api for e-commerce application

Tags: paypal

is there any api to create wallet in paypal ?  As a lot of search, I dont get api to create wallet.
Please let me find api to create wallet api using paypal. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean to create a wallet? What does one look like in PayPal?

Comment: Hi, i need to create a wallet payment system for e-commerce application in java. But there is no api to create a wallet for the user. please help me to find out. @PrestonPHX

Comment: You need to define your terms. What is a wallet? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: We are developing the e-commerce application. In that, We need transaction for the purchases by using wallet. Wallet means we store the user card details and recharge the amount to wallet. Then make payment for every purchases using that wallet money.                                                                                                           you can refer this link about to know wallet   https://developer.paypal.com/docs/wlw/paypal-integration/

Comment: Paydiant is for in-store integrations, not ecommerce. A wallet in that link refers to there being multiple payment methods, which is not what you have talked about. You appear to be interested in storage or vaulting. Wallet is the wrong word for this.  When you use the correct word, and when you describe what you are actually trying to do (store user/card details), people may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks. this api in pay pal https://developer.paypal.com/docs/wlw/b2b-mta/methods/#enrollcustomerandprovisioncard work for that ?